# Can't get handers in IIS to work

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, web-deployment

I don't know much about IIS configuration at all.

I'm running a blog based on Blogengine.net (http://dotnetblogengine.net/) I upgraded it to 2.6 (from 2.0) and was moved by my service provider to a new server that supports .NET 4.

The problem is that all http-handlers are not working. I have no direct control over the web server except for the web.config. The support at my service provider has [generated a log for me](http://ronnebybloggen.se/iis_log.rar), which gives a bit more details than a 404 when requesting something from a handler. It says HANDLER_PRECONTITION_NOT_MATCH which I suspect could be the cause of this problem.

As I said, I don't know much at all about configuration like this, the site work locally when running on IIS7.5 Express, but there seems to be the same problem when using the standard development server. My site has been non working for days now, and I'm running out of options, what to try to do!

A snippet from my web.config (exactly like the one from blogengine.net download):

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Write, Script, Execute">
  <add name="FileHandler" verb="*" path="file.axd" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpHandlers.FileHandler, BlogEngine.Core" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <add name="ImageHandler" verb="*" path="image.axd" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpHandlers.ImageHandler, BlogEngine.Core" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <add name="Syndication" verb="*" path="syndication.axd" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpHandlers.SyndicationHandler, BlogEngine.Core" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <add name="Sitemap" verb="*" path="sitemap.axd" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpHandlers.SiteMap, BlogEngine.Core" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <add name="Trackback" verb="*" path="trackback.axd" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpHandlers.TrackbackHandler, BlogEngine.Core" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <add name="Pingback" verb="*" path="pingback.axd" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpHandlers.PingbackHandler, BlogEngine.Core" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <add name="OpenSearch" verb="*" path="opensearch.axd" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpHandlers.OpenSearchHandler, BlogEngine.Core" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <add name="MetaWeblog" verb="*" path="metaweblog.axd" type="BlogEngine.Core.API.MetaWeblog.MetaWeblogHandler, BlogEngine.Core" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <add name="RSD" verb="*" path="rsd.axd" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpHandlers.RsdHandler, BlogEngine.Core" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <!--<add name="CssHandler" verb="*" path="css.axd" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpHandlers.CssHandler, BlogEngine.Core" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode"/>-->
  <add name="WebResource" path="*.js.axd" verb="*" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpHandlers.JavaScriptHandler, BlogEngine.Core" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <add name="Resource" verb="*" path="*.res.axd" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpHandlers.ResourceHandler, BlogEngine.Core" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <add name="Rating" verb="*" path="rating.axd" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpHandlers.RatingHandler, BlogEngine.Core" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <add name="Opml" verb="*" path="opml.axd" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpHandlers.OpmlHandler, BlogEngine.Core" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <add name="BlogML" verb="*" path="blogml.axd" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpHandlers.BlogMLExportHandler, BlogEngine.Core" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <add name="SIOC" verb="*" path="sioc.axd" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpHandlers.Sioc, BlogEngine.Core" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <add name="Apml" verb="*" path="apml.axd" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpHandlers.Apml, BlogEngine.Core" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <add name="Foaf" verb="*" path="foaf*.axd" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpHandlers.Foaf, BlogEngine.Core" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <add name="Html" path="*.htm" verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally solved the problem! the "Pool mode" in my service providers settings was set to classic. I changed it to "integration" and all problems went away :-)